# where does pip downloads the packages before installation

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I am trying to install PyTorch with following command after I have successfully installed cuda

```
pip3 install torch==1.10.1+cu113 torchvision==0.11.2+cu113 torchaudio===0.10.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
```

but after downloading it two times it stuck and didn't proceed to installation. now on my disk 4GB is used and I don't know where should I find the downloaded but not installed package to remove it

Comment: Where did you look so far? IIRC, `/tmp` is often used. Otherwise `~/.cache/pip` might have been used. But, no idea what OS you are using.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/ , https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_cache/